# why isnt my client.on ready function not firing?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a discord bot and the client.on ready function wont fire although it should idk why it suddenly happened my code is node.js and discord.js v12 heres my index code

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('SUP I am express, nice to met u user')

});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('welcome to express thing');
})
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
const { Prefix } = require("./Bot.json");
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.aliases = new Discord.Collection();
client.db = require("quick.db");
const Database = require("@replit/database");
const db = new Database();
client.on("ready", () => {
  client.user.setActivity('GameCore', {type: 'WATCHING'}).catch(console.log("an error ocured displaying the activity"))
  console.log(`${client.user.tag} Ready to serve in ${client.channels.cache.size} channels on ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers, for a total of ${client.users.cache.size} users.`);

})



let modules = ["works..."];

modules.forEach(function(module) {
  fs.readdir(`./commands/${module}`, function(err, files) {
    if (err)
      return new Error(
        "Missing Folder Of Commands! Example : Commands/<Folder>/<Command>.js"
      );
    files.forEach(function(file) {
      if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
      let command = require(`./commands/${module}/${file}`);
      console.log(`${command.name} Command Has Been Loaded - ✅`);
      if (command.name) client.commands.set(command.name, command);
      if (command.aliases) {
        command.aliases.forEach(alias =>
          client.aliases.set(alias, command.name)
        );
      }

    });
  });
});


client.on("message", async message => {

  if (message.author.bot) return;
   if (!message.guild) return;
   if (!message.member)
     message.member = await message.guild.fetchMember(message);
 if (!message.content.startsWith(Prefix)) return;
  


  const args = message.content
    .slice(Prefix.length)
    .trim()
    .split(" ");
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (cmd.length === 0) return;

  let command =
    client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));

  if (!command) return;

  if (command) {
  
if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"))
return message.channel.send(
"I Don't Have Enough Permission To Use This Or Any Of My Commands | Require : Administrator"
);
    command.run(client, message, args);
  }
  console.log(
    `User : ${message.author.tag} (${message.author.id}) Server : ${message.guild.name} (${message.guild.id}) Command : ${command.name}`
  );
});
client.snipe = new Discord.Collection()
client.on("messageDelete",deletedMsg=>{
client.snipe.set(deletedMsg.channel.id,deletedMsg)
})
const token = process.env['token']
client.login(token);
```

i tried to change bot token and restart the project with the new token and it still didnt work also there is no error in console and on discord the bot is offline

Comment: after logging in your bot, it should throw a message on your `console.log` or `terminal`

Comment: nvm it worked it seems like v12 is getting its support over :(

Comment: Yes, v12 and v11 getting deprecated soon